# unable to change selected state image of button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, button

I have a button action and outlet linked to my TableViewCell.h. In storyboard I'm able to set the default state image and I've added a selected state image. The problem is when selected nothing happens. In storyboard the action says 'touch up inside'. When pressed code registers in coredata, but visually nothing is changing.

In my TableViewCell.h i have the action, but because of other properties delegate to UIViewController:

```
- (IBAction)myBtn:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate tableViewCell:self];
}
```

In UIViewController:

```
-(void)tableViewCell:(TableViewCell *)cell {
// code...
}
```

Ultimately I'm trying to create a Bool for the button press so it is either in default state or selected, but also giving me troubles.

I've also tried setting the images in code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//code...
    [cell.myBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"link normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.myBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"link highlight"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

But again on selection nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Update the selected property of button in IBAction

```
- (IBAction)myBtn:(id)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
    [self.delegate tableViewCell:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[cell.myBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"link highlight"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

highlighted stae and selected state are different.

Comment: no luck with the code. I've tried it in the btn action code in the tableviewcell.m but no luck there also.